# Map Clustering in Jetpack Compose is broken

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, maps, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to implement a very simple clustering sample app using latest version of google maps compose library. When I use `Clustering` composable and run in emulator app crashes.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new project using Compose Material template
2. Add these dependencies

   ```
   implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.11.4'

   // Make sure to also include the latest version of the Maps SDK for Android
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'

   // Optionally, you can include the Compose utils library for Clustering, etc.
   implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose-utils:2.11.4'

   // Optionally, you can include the widgets library for ScaleBar, etc.
   implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose-widgets:2.11.4'
   ```
3. Add a valid google maps key inside `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

   ```
   <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="YOUR_KEY"
           />
   ```
4. Add following code to `MainActivity` inside `setContent` block

```
val singapore = LatLng(1.35, 103.87)
    
val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
    position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 10f)
}

GoogleMap(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState) {
    Clustering(items = listOf(MyMarker("foo")))
}
```

5. Create `MyMarker` data class

   ```
   data class MyMarker(val name: String): ClusterItem {
   override fun getPosition(): LatLng {
       return LatLng(1.30, 103.80)
   }

   override fun getTitle(): String? {
       return name
   }

   override fun getSnippet(): String? {
       return null
   }
   }
   ```

With those simple changes I should see a full screen map with just one unclustered marker. But instead I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView;
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager.<init>(ClusterManager.java:78)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager.<init>(ClusterManager.java:70)
        at com.google.maps.android.compose.clustering.ClusteringKt$rememberClusterManager$1.invokeSuspend(Clustering.kt:104)
.
.
.
uppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@10983c0, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@db1c8f9, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@984a03e, AndroidUiDispatcher@6e31bec]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.mapstest/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~a3y1RK-lr6Zj89PHaClKpA==/com.example.mapstest-_VL6f5R9fXVZhEg4iRdmhQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~a3y1RK-lr6Zj89PHaClKpA==/com.example.mapstest-_VL6f5R9fXVZhEg4iRdmhQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
```

What am I missing? I've followed step by step as they do on their [official repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose)

Comment: in Official Repository https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose
i found this version. 
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose-utils:2.11.2' 

check your version may b that's the issue